# How to limit checkboxes where user can only checked 2 of it?

Tags: ionic2

**HTML file**

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items" >
    <ion-item *ngFor="let driver of items; let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{driver.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="driver.checked" (ionChange)="checked(driver)" item-right></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**TS File**

```
checked(driver) {
    if (driver.checked === true) {
        this.checkedDrivers.push(driver);
    } else if (driver.checked === false) {
        this.checkedDrivers.splice(this.checkedDrivers.indexOf(driver), 1);
    } 
}
```

This is the html file and ts file for my checkbox, I manage to allow user to check the check boxes and print the value of the checkboxes but I want to limit the checkboxes where user can only checked two of it. How do I do it?

Comment: you mean you want to disable checkboxes once two are selected?

Comment: Yes, I want to disable the checkboxes once two are selected.

Comment: why not have a check in `checked()` function?

Comment: How do I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a check in `checked()` to see if two items are checked and use a boolean variable to enable/disable the checkboxes.

```
<ion-list *ngIf="items" >
    <ion-item *ngFor="let driver of items; let i = index">
        <ion-label>{{driver.name}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox [(ngModel)]="driver.checked" [disabled]="isCheckboxDisabled" (ionChange)="checked(driver)" item-right></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

In your TS file, set `isCheckboxDisabled` as false,

```
isCheckboxDisabled:boolean=false;

checked(driver) {
    if (driver.checked === true) {
        this.checkedDrivers.push(driver);
    } else if (driver.checked === false) {
       this.checkedDrivers.splice(this.checkedDrivers.indexOf(driver), 1);
    }

    //check for two selected.
    if(this.items.filter(driver=> driver.checked).length===2){
        this.isCheckboxDisabled=true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hey, it's working fine, but once a user selects one checkbox he can't edit his choice. How to achieve this.